# All Laravel files got duplicated

Tags: laravel, github

I don't know how it happened, but all my file inside my laravel project got duplicated. Now i have to push so many files that basically GitHub tells me it cant't push all of them. I tried to move everything to another folder, create a new repository ecc but nothing seems to be working because all the files stay duplicated. This project should be pushed before this evening so i cannot start over. I'd hate to have waisted days for a project i cannot present. Do you have any advices at all that could help, or something to delete all the duplicates... See the photo attached to understand better what is happening [duplicate files and 10K changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pgIp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete (or move) the "node_modules" folder and commit file deletion in your repository

If there is nothing to commit (no deletion), then skip to next step.

Add The "node_modules" to your `.gitignore` (add this line)

```
node_modules/
```

And commit it.

Now You can `npm install` or move back the "node_modules" folder and your repository is fixed.